# Codeception selenium WaitForJS and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I have a loading waiting for a hidden field to be fill.  i would like to wait for the ajax to be loaded to go to the next step. i tried to use the waitForJS to do this but i dont know how to built the javascript condition.

I already try with an other condtion but it doesnt work, i really need the ajax to be loaded to go the next step.

```
$I->waitForJS(
    15000, 
    "(function myJavascriptFunction() {       
        var monChamp = document.getElementById('data-com_product_id');
        if (monChamp.value != '') {
            return true;    
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
     })()"
);
```

Every suggestions wil be welcome. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$I->waitForJS("return $.active == 0;",10);
```

if you use webdriver in codeception.
Tested it just now and works like charm.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I use Webdriver mod now, more methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$this->waitForJs('return document.readyState == "complete"', 10);
```